# How to hook one event for block with many elements

Tags: javascript, events, checkbox, onclick

I have this markup:

```
<fieldset class="checkbxr full small" onclick="alert('test')">
    <label for="" class="fat_label">Category</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="true_checkb" id="">
    <span class="dmy_checkb"></span>
</fieldset>
```

This is some dummy checkbox solution. Everything is ok, but i need to hook one `onclick` event for whole `fieldset`. So if i do like below i have 3 alerts, for all of elements inisde, so my event fires 3 times. How to set this for only `fieldset` and make one event call? Thx for help.

This is fiddle with js and some css: http://jsfiddle.net/VeT6y/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/YK3TU/ works as expected?

Comment: yes, so why i have 3 alerts instead of one?

Answer (score 0):

You need to cancel the event from bubbling depending on what was clicked....
here is a script to do that (in pure javascript - it is easier to do in jQuery - as you can check if there is a class on the event source for example and cancel it then). This script checks if the tag clicked was FIELDSET, if it is not cancels the bubble, if it is pops an alert.

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/YK3TU/2/

code:

HTML:

```
<fieldset class="checkbxr full small" onclick="javascript:doSomething()">
    <label for="" class="fat_label">Category</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="true_checkb" id="">
    <span class="dmy_checkb"></span>
</fieldset>
```

Javascript:

```
function doSomething(e) {
    var targ;
    if (!e) var e = window.event;
    if (e.target) targ = e.target;
    else if (e.srcElement) targ = e.srcElement;
    if (targ.nodeType == 3) // defeat Safari bug
        targ = targ.parentNode;
    console.log(targ)
    if (targ.tagName!="FIELDSET") {
     cancelBubble(e)   
    } else {
     doMyThing()   
    }
}
function cancelBubble(e) {
 var evt = e ? e:window.event;
 if (evt.stopPropagation)    evt.stopPropagation();
 if (evt.cancelBubble!=null) evt.cancelBubble = true;
}
function doMyThing(){
    alert("this is a test")

}
```